# Javascript: Matching Objects in Multiple Arrays of Objects + Aliases

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to match multiple arrays and build another array whenever there is match. The key could match in any number of arrays or none at all.

```
[ [{ 'a': 13 }, { 'b': 62 }, { 'c': 93 }, { 'd': 52 }],
  [{ 's': 15 }, { 'y': 15 }, { 'x': 78 }, { 'd': 84 }],
  [{ 't': 35 }, { 'd': 33 }, { 'x': 12 }, { 'c': 62 }] ]
```

Desired result:

```
[ {label: c,  arr1: 93,    arr2: null,  arr3: 63},
  {label: d,  arr1: 52,    arr2: 84,    arr3: 33},
  {label: x,  arr1: null,  arr2: 78,    arr3: 12} ]
```

.

```
label   arr1    arr2    arr3
============================
c       93      null    62
d       52      84      33
x       null    78      12
```

A more advanced question to go along with that. Is it possible to alias some keys. Eg. perhaps 'b' is also known as 'y', and 's' as 't'.

Comment: What code have you started with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let output = [];
let aliases = {'b': ['y'], 's': ['t']};
let totalArrays = yourArray.length;

yourArray.forEach((innerArray, i) => 
   innerArray.forEach(obj =>{
      for(var key in obj){
         let current = output.find(e => e.label == key || (aliases[e.label] || []).indexOf(key) !== -1);
            if(!current){
               current = { label: key };
               for(let i = 0; i < totalArrays; i++){
                   current['arr' + (i + 1)] = null;
               }
               output.push(current);
           }

           current['arr'+ (i +1)] = obj[key];
       } 
 }));
```

Comment: Amazing man. It would literally take me hours to figure something like this out. How can I remove the object that didn't have any matches?
http://jsbin.com/vudedokaqo/edit?js,output

Comment: The output entries are added dynamically when label appears for the first time, so there shouldn't be any objects without matches. I assume that you won't have any objects like { 'a' : undefined } in your source array.